# Match characters of a string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

If I call `matcher.match('bad')` it should return a list of all permutations of `'bad'` which exist in a provided list. In this example, output will be `['abd']`. So far this is what i have tried but I can't seem to match this pattern.

```
class Matcher():
    def __init__(self, string_list):
        self.string_list = string_list

    def match(self, string_match):
        matched_list = [string for string in string_list if string_match in string]
        return matched_list

string_list = ['abd', 'abdd', 'fret', 'gilk', 'lokm']
matcher = Matcher(string_list)
print(matcher.match('abd'))
```

Comment: so, to be clear, your input is `'bad'` and the output you want is `['abd']`, and the output has to be in the predefined `string_list` ?

Comment: @jp_data_analysis you are right.

Comment: And 'aba' or 'ab' shouldn't match too? Every character in your input has to occur exactly once (more precise: as often as in your pattern, but in arbitrary order)?

Comment: @userunknown True that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an O(*n* log *n*) solution:

```
string_list = ['abd', 'abdd', 'fret', 'gilk', 'lokm']

my_str = 'bad'

[x for x in string_list if sorted(my_str) == sorted(x)]  # ['abd']
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I will see if I can improve it in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `collections.Counter()` for this:

```
from collections import Counter

string_list = ['abd', 'abdd', 'fret', 'gilk', 'lokm']

my_str = 'bad'

print([x for x in string_list if Counter(my_str) == Counter(x)])
# ['abd']
```